# .net: Store SQL query pairs in array

Tags: sql, .net, arrays, interpreter

I have a solution for this, but its more of a workaround than something to use in production. 
The workaround is basically a simple sql interpreter written by myself, but I don't think it will work 100%
Assumed I have this query: 
**...Field1 Like 'Value1%' AND(Field2=Value2)...**

Is there a way to get an array that looks something like this:
**[0]["field"] = Field1

[0]["value"] = Value1%

[1]["field"] = Field2

[1]["value"] = Value2**
Thanks in advance for any hints and tips!
And I code in .net c# right now. But It's no problem to translate for me! :D

Comment: Basically, you're after an SQL parser and AST?

Comment: Yes I am. Is there a built in Parser in .Net? I couldn't find one, that's why I asked here. If it is not built in, then I have to write my own one.

Comment: I believe SMO has one. It is the one powering SSMS and it is publicly exposed.